# How can i get 35 focal lenght from photo properties?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I work with camera2API and i need to get `focal lenght` property.

I found one way to get it from camera characteristic

```
float[] f = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);

            for (float d : f) {
                Logger.logGeneral("LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS : " + d);
            }
```

but this approach retern back value like `3.8` or smth close to it. It depend of the device. But this value have to be approximately close to `30-35`...

Then i found another solution. When i take a photo i opened photo properties and saw exextly what i get and what i need

[image]

I tryed to get this property directly from image

```
private JSONObject getJsonProperties() {
    JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();

    final ExifInterface exif = getExifInterface();
    final String [] tagProperties = {TAG_DATETIME, TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED, TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME,
            TAG_FLASH, TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH, TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF, TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP,
            TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF,
            TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD, TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, TAG_ISO, TAG_MAKE,
            TAG_MODEL, TAG_ORIENTATION, TAG_SUBSEC_TIME, TAG_SUBSEC_TIME_DIG, TAG_SUBSEC_TIME_ORIG, TAG_WHITE_BALANCE};

    for (String tag : tagProperties){
        try {
            properties.put(tag, exif.getAttribute(tag));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return properties;
}

private ExifInterface getExifInterface() {
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(ImageSaver.getImageFilePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return exif;
}
```

I combine set of entire properties and of course include one that i very need `TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH`. But again i get wrong valeu like this `473/100`... i don't know what does it mean... Valeu have to be approximatly `30-35`...

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Eventyally i found the answer.

According @Aleks G

> The 35mm equivalent would be your obtained focal length multiplied by a certain number, known as crop factor. This factor is very much different for different manufacturers and even models. For example, for many Nikon DSLR cameras it's 1.5; for many Canon DSLRs it's 1.6; for Apple iPhone 5 it's 6.99, for Samsung Galaxy S3 it's 7.6, and so on.
>
> To the best of my knowledge, Android does not provide an API to determine the crop factor of the device's camera.
>
> There's one trick you can try using though. Once you take a photo with the device's camera, some devices will populate FocalLengthIn35mmFilm exif tag - so you can try using this technique. Not all phones do this though, for example, my Huawei doesn't.
>
> Some other devices will populate two fields for Focal Length - the first being the actual focal length used, the second being the 35mm equivalent. Again, not all do. The same Huawei phone doesn't, but my iPhone 5 does.
>
> To make the long story short, there's no guaranteed way of figuring out the 35mm equivalent from the focal length you obtain on the device.

And eventually i just add to my list of properties such tag

```
TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_35MM_FILM
```

And now if it is available i can get it